# Select specific keys from YouTube API response

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, parsing

I am fetching data from YouTube API V3 using 'googleapiclient' python.
The response is vast and all I want is to parse some keys, then append them to a csv file.

In order to work fast and not loop over each item, each page has 50 items and multiple pages estimate number around 50, thus if I loop to extract the keys I have to do 250 iteration maybe more.

So, I decided to use pandas to speed up the process, but I don't know how yet.

Could you give me an idea how to speed up the parsing process, preferably using panda?

Here is one of the items from the response:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "9C4YPSA6KJ2_ZQe6k0khyWyZw4U",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "DE",
  "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 569, "resultsPerPage": 50 },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "-tjutsrDQfkNJkMufUBxwHakEkE",
      "id": { "kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "wnnKjI1m2Ug" },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-11-14T10:00:11Z",
        "channelId": "UCVdfgrCLfJQfO5EgPlzaYAQ",
        "title": "Was ist XML? Einfach und schnell erkl\u00e4rt!",
        "description": "Werbung: Jetzt Premium Mitgliedschaft sichern ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wnnKjI1m2Ug/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wnnKjI1m2Ug/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wnnKjI1m2Ug/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Programmieren Starten",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2019-11-14T10:00:11Z"
      }
    }
```

I would like to extract from each item:
['id'] > ['videoId']
['snippet'] > ['title']
['snippet'] > ['channelTitle']

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just wanted to add, that `pandas` is notoriously slow for this type of workload. As it is a very simple problem you have, I would suggest not using `pandas` if you can. See below for a quick perf comparison I was able to put together.

```py
from timeit import timeit
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "9C4YPSA6KJ2_ZQe6k0khyWyZw4U",
  "nextPageToken": "CDIQAA",
  "regionCode": "DE",
  "pageInfo": { "totalResults": 569, "resultsPerPage": 50 },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "-tjutsrDQfkNJkMufUBxwHakEkE",
      "id": { "kind": "youtube#video", "videoId": "wnnKjI1m2Ug" },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2019-11-14T10:00:11Z",
        "channelId": "UCVdfgrCLfJQfO5EgPlzaYAQ",
        "title": "Was ist XML? Einfach und schnell erkl\u00e4rt!",
        "description": "Werbung: Jetzt Premium Mitgliedschaft sichern ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wnnKjI1m2Ug/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wnnKjI1m2Ug/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/wnnKjI1m2Ug/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Programmieren Starten",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
        "publishTime": "2019-11-14T10:00:11Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}


def extract(item):
    snippet = item['snippet']
    return [item["id"]["videoId"], snippet["title"], snippet["channelTitle"]]


print('Pandas:           ', timeit("_ = pd.json_normalize(data['items'])[['id.videoId', 'snippet.title', 'snippet.channelTitle']]",
             number=1000, globals=globals()))

print('Dict key lookup:  ', timeit("""
for item in data["items"]:
    _ = extract(item)
""", number=1000, globals=globals()))
```

Results:

```
Pandas:            0.7727613999741152
Dict key lookup:   0.00024690001737326384
```

I think these results speak for themselves. That said, `pandas` certainly does have its place and its use case, but I daresay this does not seem to be one of them.

Comment: very helpful, Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I would be surprised if you could use pandas to help speed this up.  Pandas is a library for manipulating and processing dataframes.  Perhaps you could use pandas to construct a dataframe of this data, or to save it as a CSV, but I don't think it will help in the basic processing.

To process this data I think you just need to apply the function you want, i.e. gathering those three datapoints you are looking for, to the data you have.  Your response is coming back as json, so parse it as json, take the items list, and then for each item in your items list extract the data you want.

```
import json

item_list = json.loads(YOUR_RESPONSE)["items"]

def extract(item):
    return [item["id"]["videoId"], item["snippet"]["title"], item["snippet"]["channelTitle"]]

for item in item_list:
    print(extract(item))
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the extracted information once you have it, but this approach will let you get the values you are care about out of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to flatten the nested data. Combined with filtering the desired columns this would make (assuming the input is a dict called `data`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(data['items'])[['id.videoId', 'snippet.title', 'snippet.channelTitle']]
```

result:

|  | id.videoId | snippet.title | snippet.channelTitle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | wnnKjI1m2Ug | Was ist XML? Einfach und schnell erklärt! | Programmieren Starten |

Comment: Exactly what I am looking for, but as @rv.kvetch answered, pandas is too slow compared to normal parsing. I will mark this as the answer because I was looking for this technique.